# What is the meaning of "\!" in iptables?

Tags: iptables

I found this nice cheat sheet [here](https://cheatography.com/inqu1sitive/cheat-sheets/nix-cheet-sheet/) and wondering what is the meaning of `\!` in the iptables command?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dest­ina­tio­n-port 13327 \! -d 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`iptables` manual](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables.8), the `-d` option (as well as a number of other options) may be prefixed with an optional `!` character. Doing so negates the sense of the test.

The `\` in front of `!` is one of the shell (most shells) quoting/escaping operators. `\!` here would be the same as `'!'` or `"!"`.

The `!` character does not need to be escaped in most common shells as it's not special by itself when part of the arguments to a command, so that `\` here is superfluous. Whether `\!`, `"!"`, `'!'` or `!` is used, a literal `!` argument will be passed to `iptables`.